# Pitch accent for 〜ごろ(に)

Tags: particles, suffixes, pitch-accent

I can't find any source for how the pitch accent of 〜ごろ(ni) works.  Does it function like any other particle, carrying the pitch of the previous word, or does it act more like a suffix like 〜人 or 〜語; changing the pronunciation of the previous word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It brings up the "tail" of the preceding word.

> 一時　[いちじ]{LHL}
>
> 一時頃　[いちじごろ]{LHHHL}

> 二時　[にじ]{HL}
>
> ニ時頃　[にじごろ]{LHHL}